# Prove the inequality $1/x^2 + x^2/4 \le 5/4$

Tags: inequality

Exercise for reference down below:
[image]

For any x you pick in the interval [1,2] you have to prove that the inequality in the title is true.

Would like some help in solving this or maybe an idea that I can work on, I don't know how & if I can solve it by using the common denominator 4*x^2.

in case you might spot a mistake in my attempt at solving, I am going to write it here:

> $(4+x^4)/(4*x^2)$ <= $5/4$
>
> > $4+x^4 <= 5x^2$
> >
> > > $4+x^4$ is between [5,20] and $5*x^2$ is between [5,20]

After "step" 3 I didn't know how to continue as I thought it was a dead end.

Comment: what you had tried?

Comment: @Khosrotash edited just now to show you how I've tried with the common denominator.

I've also tried using Titu's inequality which you can find here: https://www.eutopiagardens.org/page/01-temp/stiinta-tehnologie/inventii-descoperiri-idei-geniale/inegalitatea-lui-titu-andreescu/2372950

After using Titu's I would get: 1/x^2 + x^2/4 >= (1+x)^2/(x^2+4) and RHS would be smaller than 5/4 and that didn't really help (I might've even used Titu wrong).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @cezar Titu's likely wouldn't work because the inequality is true only in the restricted domain. You'd need something else.

Comment: Do you know calculus?

Comment: if you mean limits, derivatives, integrals etc. not yet, sorry

Comment: then you won't appreciate my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As an idea:take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{4} , x\in[1,2]\\ $$show that range of that function is $y\leq \frac54$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply throughout by $x^2$, shift terms to one side, and factorize.

The inequality you want to show becomes

> $(x^2 - 4) (x^2 - 1) \leq 0$

which is obvious in the given domain.

Comment: I think there is a `$` missing in your quoted text.

Comment: @BookOfFlames Fixed thanks. IMO you can directly edit minor typos like this.

Comment: Thank you and indeed the exercise looks more simpler than I've thought initially!

Answer (score 1):

Equality holds at the ends of the interval ($x=1$ and $x=2$),

and the function $x^{-2}+x^2/4$ is concave upward

because its second derivative is $6x^{-4}+1/2$ is always positive.